# black rect instead of QtextDocument content in QPrinter pdf output

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qtcore, qprinter

So I needed border in QtextFrame in a pdf (QPrinter's pdf output). Following is the code I used

```
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTextFrameFormat>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTextFrame>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPrinter>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextDocument doc;
    QPixmap map(1024, 1024);
    map.fill(Qt::white);
    QPainter p;
    p.begin(&map);
    p.fillRect(QRect(0,0, 4, map.height()), QBrush(Qt::red));
    p.end();

    QTextFrameFormat frameFormat;
    QBrush bruh(map);
    bruh.setColor(Qt::transparent);
    frameFormat.setBackground(bruh);
    frameFormat.setPadding(6);
    auto cur = new QTextCursor(&doc);
    auto frame = cur->insertFrame(frameFormat);
    auto curf = new QTextCursor(frame);
    curf->insertText("Hello this is qt program!");

    QPrinter pdf;
    pdf.setOutputFileName("E:\\test.pdf");
    pdf.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    doc.print(&pdf);

    QTextEdit edt;
    edt.setDocument(&doc);
    edt.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But the pdf output is different from the what is shown in QTextEdit
pdf  (Only a single black line no content)
[image]

Text Edit output which is what I needed
[image]

Comment: I just tested your code on my machine. It produces your expected PDF output. So the issue seems to be with yout setup

Comment: I am using msys2 build I will try compiling with other versioj or msvc let you guys know. I spend my whole day on this

Comment: It works on Ubuntu but not on windows tried mith msvc also.

Comment: I thinks then it's qt bug or something

Comment: Worked fine on my Windows 7... Qt 5.12.4 MSVC 64b and MinGw 32b, Qt 5.9.4 MinGw 32b. The output is raster though, so it scales with the document and looks pixelated at anything but original size. I wouldn't use a painter for text personally (or scalable graphics). Maybe go with that HTML solution/hack instead :)  Also I'm not sure why anyone would build on Windows using msys... yet another layer between the app and WinAPI.

Comment: strange The ubuntu produced pdf looks different on windows(black rectangle instead of text)

Comment: msys provides prebuild goodies

Comment: Sorry guys when viewed with explorer or adobe I see black rectangle but chrome gets the correct output.

Comment: I viewed with the Adobe viewer (Acrobat? whatever it's called these days.) On this msys thing... what goodies? Well doesn't matter I suppose, but I would make sure to use the version of MinGw recommended for the corresponding Qt version. Others will not be tested and you could be chasing bugs into oblivion. BTDT.